# Mobile Chrome browser displays different than other mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I am trying to build a responsive webpage with this image of the cover of Mr Robot. It actually does work, only the mobile Chrome browser makes trouble.

As you can see on the second image below, the cover image is slightly hanging over the right end of the screen and I don't know why.
Does someone has a clue why Chrome is making trouble in this case?

Here's the code I used:

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="..." class="cover">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  .wrapper img.cover {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

How it looks on Safari, Firefox and Opera:

[image: How it looks on Safari, Firefox and Opera]

How it looks on Chrome:

[image: How it looks on Chrome]

Thank you!

Comment: can you share your inspected element screenshot.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Ev7WxQ3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly set a limit to the size of your picture...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="..." class="cover" style="width:300px;height:800px;">
</div>
```

the numbers are just estimates, just trial and error for you I guess. 
Best of luck!